# Karabiner Elements Fn + F keys to volume control on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, karabiner

I'm using a Durgod keyboard (replacing an old Mac keyboard) and would like to have <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to lower volume and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to increase volume. Those are the keys I use for volume control on the Mac keyboard. It doesn't work right now with the Durgod keyboard. How do I make this possible using Karabiner Elements?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot of my configuration
[image]

To achieve what you asked, try select f11 to volume_decrement and f12 to volume_increment, and toggle the "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have my f11 and f12 keys set like in your screenshot right now, and I can adjust the volume this way without having to press Fn. But I need it to only work when I press Fn because I have shortcuts assigned to the f11 and f12 keys.

Comment: Do you have "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" checked?

Comment: Yup, I do have that option checked.

Comment: In `System Preferences > Keyboard`, have you selected "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"? (If you select this one it will reverse the option you have in karabiner.

Comment: I tried that, but it unfortunately didn't have any effect.